# Why doesn't the JVM operate directly on the local variable array for assignment?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

[image]

[image]

---

I'm learnning about JVM memory model and I have a question ,why jvm not operate directly on the local variable array when assigning variable `a` ,but instead uses operand stack first and then pops them into the local variable array?

Comment: See [What is the role of operand stack in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61321741/2711488)

Comment: **tl;dr** because there's no bytecode instruction to directly write a value to a local variable. All values go via the stack, that's just how stack based machines work.

Comment: @JoachimSauer except for `iinc` that operates directly on a local variable. I know, calling Java bytecode a “stack based machine” is very widespread, but I wouldn’t agree. It doesn’t support pushing or popping a dynamic number of elements. You can easily transform it to an index based instruction set and back, the use of an operand stack is just for a denser encoding compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @Holger: interesting, I wasn't aware of that exception. They probably thought it's a frequent enough use case that it's worth "breaking" the strict model for.

Comment: @JoachimSauer as said, my point of view is that it isn’t meant to be a strict model at all. The main goal is to allow dense code, so it’s no problem to add exceptions wherever it fits. Increment seems to be common enough (counting loops, etc) to justify such an exception. The non-obvious consequence is that using `int` in a counting loop always produces denser code than using `byte`, `char`, or `short`. In the past, there also was the `ret` instruction using a direct variable index, but that has no relevance today…

Comment: The reason why the JVM can't be called a real stack machine is: At every instruction, you exactly know all the types on the stack, and how big the stack is.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that’s what I meant with “It doesn’t support pushing or popping a dynamic number of elements” and “You can easily transform it to an index based instruction set and back”.

Comment: Yeah, figured. Just thought it might be useful to rephrase it differently.