# How do stack machines efficiently store data types of different sizes?

Tags: stack, virtual-machine, bytecode

Suppose I have the following primitive stack implementation for a virtual machine:

```
unsigned long stack[512];
unsigned short top = 0;

void push(unsigned long qword) {
    stack[top] = qword;
    top++;
}

void pop() {
    top--;
}

unsigned long get() {
    return top-1;
}
```

This stack actually works fine (*except that it doesn't check for an overflow*) but I now have the following problem: **It is quite inefficient.**

Here is an example:
Let's say I want to push a byte onto the stack.  I would now have to cast it to a long and then push it onto the stack. But now a whole 7 bytes are not being used. This feels kind of wrong.

So now I have the following question:
**How do stack machines efficiently store data types of different sizes? Do they do the same as in this implementation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "one true" way of doing this, and the Java VM uses a few different strategies. All types less than 32-bits in size are widened to 32-bits. Pushing 1 byte to the stack effectively pushes 4 bytes to the stack. The benefit is simplicity when there are fewer native value sizes to deal with.

Another strategy is used for 64-bit values. They occupy two stack slots instead of one. The JVM has specific opcodes which indicate which type of value they expect on the stack, and the verifier ensures that no opcode is attempting to access a variable off the stack that doesn't match the type that should be there.

A third strategy is used for object references. The actual pointer size can be 32 bits or 64 bits, depending on the CPU capabilities, whether the JVM is running in 64-bit mode, etc. The JVM has specific opcodes for handling object references, and the verifier checks this too.

Answer (score 3):

There are different metrics of efficiency. Using an eight bytes `long` to store a single byte will raise the memory consumption. On the other hand, memory is not the major concern on most of today’s machines. Further, a stack is a pre-allocated amount of memory, typically. So as long as not the entire memory block has been exhausted, it is entirely irrelevant whether the unused seven bytes are within that `long` or on the other side of the location marked by `top`.

In terms of CPU time, you don’t gain any advantage of transferring a quantity smaller than the hardware’s bus size. In the best case, it makes no difference. In the worst case, transferring a single byte boils down to reading a `long` from memory, manipulating one byte of it and writing the `long` back. In the latter case, it would be more efficient to expand the byte to long, to overwrite all eight bytes explicitly.

This is reflected by the design of the Java bytecode, for example. It does not only drop support for pushing and popping quantities smaller than 32 bit, it doesn’t even support arithmetic instructions for them¹. So for most use cases, you don’t even know that a quantity could be a `byte` before pushing. Only formal parameter types and array types may refer to `byte`.

But note that a JVM isn’t even a stack engine in the narrowest sense. There is no support for pushing and popping arbitrary numbers of items. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61321741/2711488), expressing the intent using a stack allows very compact instructions. But Java bytecode doesn’t allow branching to code locations with a different number of items on the stack. So it doesn’t support pushing or popping items in a loop. In other words, for each instruction, the actual offset into the stack is predictable and also the operand types are known. So it’s always possible to transform Java bytecode to an IR not using a stack straight-forwardly. Such transformed code could use instructions with arbitrary operand sizes, if that has a benefit on the particular target architecture.

¹ And that was accounting for hardware in use a quarter century ago